# PI control signal

Tags: python, motordriver, pid-controller

i am trying to translate my PI control signal 'u[k]' into a duty cycle ouput with error e[k] governing directional output....but i think it could be better.

So I am using if statements to concentrate the value of u between 0 to 100 since that is the dc range. (I cant seem to add an "abs" statement to u or u[k] anywhere to keep it in the postiive realm, so if there is another way please let me know.)

Then the value of u[k] will become the dc cycle throughtout the script. if error e[k] is positive than to rotate CW, if error is negative then to rotate CCW. At the same time, u[k] will contorl the speed of the motor allowing it to slow down or speed up as it reaches the desired angle. let me know

I am still having the error

"ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Below is the snippet of code I am struggling with. Any help is appreciated

```
def MotorClockwise():
    GPIO.output(Motor1, GPIO.LOW) # Motor will move in clockwise direction.
    GPIO.output(Motor2, GPIO.HIGH)
    
    
def MotorAntiClockwise():
    GPIO.output(Motor1, GPIO.HIGH) # Motor will move in anti-clockwise direction.
    GPIO.output(Motor2, GPIO.LOW)
    
def MotorStop():
    GPIO.output(Motor1, GPIO.LOW) # Motor will stop.
    GPIO.output(Motor2, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(PWMPin, GPIO.LOW)


#PI controller settings
Kp = 12
Ki = 8 #integral Time

r = 4.5 #setpoint angle to be achieved
#intialization
e = np.zeros(N+2)
u = np.zeros(N+2)
  
for k in range(N+1):
 
    e[k] = r - encoder_angle #calucalted error
    #print (f"{e[k]} Error Detected")
    #time.sleep(.5)
    
    # PI Controller - produces new contrl signal
    u[k] = u[k-1] + Kp*(e[k] - e[k-1]) + (Kp/Ki)*e[k] # discrete version of PI controller
   # y[k+1] = (1+Ts*a)*y[k] + Ts*b*u[k] #discrete deff equ of process
```

########################BELOW IS WHERE I AM STRUGGELING

```
while True:
    if (u > 100):
        u = 100;
        if (e[k] > 0) :
            PwmValue.ChangeDutyCycle(u)
            MotorClockwise()
    if (u < -100):
        u = -100;
        if (e[k] < 0):
            PwmValue.ChangeDutyCycle(u)
            MotorAntiClockwise()
        
    if (e[k] == 0) and (r == encoder_angle):
        MotorStop()
        print(f"Motor Stopped & Holding at {encoder_angle} Degrees")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `if` statement you are trying to compare `u` to numbers as a conditional. `u` is an [array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html). In order to make the comparison valid, the types must be comparable. You cannot compare an array and a number - the outcome of `[1, 3] > 2` is undefined. Try using numpy's `np.any` or `np.all` like your error suggests, python's `any(u)` or `all(u)`, or indexing the `u` array (`u[k]`) to get a number for comparison.